# Append to XML in jquery not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, xml, webkit

OK, this is the code I am using, to maintain a list of bookmarks:

```
    var newBookmark="<mark text='"+$(this).siblings(".newbookmarktext").val()+"' page='"+page+"' />";
    if ($(xmlDoc).find("file[name='"+file+"']").length==0)
        $(xmlDoc).children("bookmarks").first().append("<file name='"+file+"'/>");
    $(xmlDoc).find("file[name='"+file+"']").first().append(newBookmark);
```

When I run this in firefox, it runs perfectly, adding the new bookmark to the list, under the filename entry.

However under Chrome - and other webkit browsers - it doesn't work. As far as I can tell, the append of the  entry is just not functioning. The xml it is adding is fine - the file is simply a file name - but it doesn't run.

I have looked through the other SE entries on Append not working, but they seem to be html issues and problems. I cannot find any other indications of jquery methods like this not working across browsers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7fTf2/ - this is a fiddle with the code tweaked a bit to get it to run stand alone.

Comment: I have tried to change the last line to "alert($(xmlDoc).children("bookmarks").children().length);" which illustrates the problem a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the problem, but I don't completely understand. If I make the added entries JQ values, it seems to work. so my code needs to be:

```
var newBookmark=$("<mark text='hello' page='1' />");
if ($(xmlDoc).find("file[name='"+file+"']").length===0)
    $(xmlDoc).children("bookmarks").first().append($("<file name='"+file+"'/>"));
$(xmlDoc).find("file[name='"+file+"']").first().append(newBookmark);
```

if it is to run in Chrome/webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  Firefox worked fine, but chrome wouldn't append my xml snippet.  Tried everything.  Finally have a solution that works for both chrome and firefox.  Here is my original code which didn't work, and below that the solution:

```
 var xml = $.parseXML(o.text);
 $(xml).find('documentGroups').append('<documentGroup documentGroupID="0" name="Default Group"/>');
```

The above fails, but the below works.  I believe it is because the node must be created as a member of the same XML Document in order to be inserted, and the above code creates the new documentGroup node in a different XML Document.  The below code forces the creation of the node inside the same XML Document to which it will be inserted.

```
 var xml = $.parseXML(o.text);
 var defaultGroup = xml.createElement('documentGroup'); 
 $(defaultGroup).attr('documentGroupID', '0').attr('name', 'Default Group');
 $(xml).find('documentGroups').append(defaultGroup);
```

I believe this should be fixed within JQuery.  Using the first all-jQuery syntax, Firefox inserts the node just fine.  Chrome should as well; otherwise, jQuery isn't meeting its goal to make its syntax work cross-browser.  jQuery is great, I don't mean to knock it.  Just commenting on where I think the problem is.

Also, I've seen commented elsewhere that with `$('<node/>')` syntax jQuery uses innerHTML to parse the string instead of the browser's XML parser, which would prevent non-HTML syntax from parsing correctly.